# getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frg_video_listing_video_listing_fragment);

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

pardon me if this is a stupid error. there are two fragments in my activity layout (xml) and in order to let them communicate i am trying to get the instance of one fragment inside my main activity. i have done it earlier but this time it throws erro (required videolisting fragment but found fragment) i am not sure what i have given wrong. might be just a silly mistake. can you please assist. Thanks in advance.

**below is code snippet:**

```
public class VideoListingActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements FilterFragment.OnFilterItemSelectedListener{

 public VideoListFragment videoListFragment;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_listing);

    videoListFragment =(VideoListFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frg_video_listing_video_listing_fragment);

}
```

**below is the layout:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="my activity context">


    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/filter_fragment_height"
        android:name="com.text1.text2.text3.pkg.FilterFragment"
        android:id="@+id/frg_video_listing_filter_fragment"
        ></fragment>

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:name="com.text1.text2.text3.pkg.VideoListFragment"
        android:id="@+id/frg_video_listing_video_listing_fragment"
        ></fragment>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Below is fragment class code

```
package com.rrdtech.vidyavaan.android.Fragments;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.rrdtech.vidyavaan.android.R;


public class VideoListFragment extends ListFragment {
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return     inflater.inflate(R.layout.video_list_fragment,container,false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
}
}
```

Below is stack trace

```
Error:(22, 91) error: inconvertible types
required: VideoListFragment
found:    Fragment
```

Comment: Can you show the fragment class code?

Comment: Could you please provide the stack trace of the raised exception?

Comment: Stack trace and what line causes the exception (I'm guessing I know which one is it) would be helpful!

Comment: the line causing problem is  *************  videoListFragment =(VideoListFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frg_video_listing_video_listing_fragment);
     *********** in my activity holding the fragments

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to add the class attribute in XML.

```
<fragment
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:name="com.text1.text2.text3.pkg.VideoListFragment"
    class="com.text1.text2.text3.pkg.VideoListFragment"
    android:id="@+id/frg_video_listing_video_listing_fragment"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You Need to know

1. You are using support library for Fragment using
   `getSupportFragmentManager()`, In this case you should always use support package classes.
2. `VideoListFragment` extending `android.app.ListFragment;` **instead of** `android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;` (this thing causes the error). And make sure fragment layout has `ListView` with `"@android:id/list"` id.

Comment: tried above... i get NullPointerException . i tried getSupportFragmentManager().findViewById(R.id.fragment_id).getClass()  and got below  error                                                                                     Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null object reference

Comment: why r u using `getClass()`, this much is enough `videoListFragment =(VideoListFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frg_video_listing_video_listing_fragment);` AND if you dont have fragment with that id you will get that error.

Comment: getClass() i was using just to check what class object i am receiving . i was getting nullPointer Excpetion.